# how does startActivity(this, OtherActivity.class) use Context object to start an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I started reading about Context And I am a bit confused.

I found the following definition.

```
The Context class is an “Interface to global information about an application environment.”
```

> here I am not understanding what android application environment is?

we can use **1. getAssets() 2. getResources() 3. getPackageManager() 4. getString() 5. getSharedPrefsFile()** methods ,we can also start an activity ,broadcast an Intent using Context.

I think,The above methods(bolded) provide app's global data to the app,

> Are these Resources known as App global data?
>
> So for starting activity ,what global information is used by Android
>   System?
>
> How does a View use Context (what information it gets from Context)?

I am so much confused about the concept of Context class and how all these things are related.

Please provide any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through Context details. I think these things can help you understand the idea of context.

```
    View.getContext():
 Returns the context the view is currently running in. Usually the currently active Activity.

    Activity.getApplicationContext():
 Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside of). Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the current Activity.

    ContextWrapper.getBaseContext():
 If you need access to a Context from within another context, you use a ContextWrapper. The Context referred to from inside that ContextWrapper is accessed via getBaseContext().
```